# The cordova plugin 'mfilechooser'' is not working on Android phone with cordova 6.3.1

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, filechooser

The mfilechooser plugin to work for my cordova based app on the android emulator or device. No errors are reported  but the chooser is not launching.

Here is the snippet of my code.

**index.js**

```
 function choose(){

    window.plugins.mfilechooser.open([], function (uri) {

      alert(uri);

    }, function (error) {

        alert(error);

    });
    }
    function onDeviceReady() { 
    }

    function domLoaded(){
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    }
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
            default-src 'self';
            connect-src *;
            style-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:      'unsafe-inline';
            img-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:;
            frame-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:;
            font-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:;
            media-src *;>

        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="domLoaded()">
        <div>
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        </div>
        <div>

             <button onClick="choose()">choose file</button>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Cordova 6.3.1
file chooser : https://github.com/MaginSoft/MFileChooser

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you fixed the issue? I am also facing the same issue. Any advise.

Comment: No solution .. Does not work with SDK 23 and cordova 6.3.1 . I have tried  most of the recommended plugin but I am still stuck.. Currently , I am using this plugin[ http://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git]/ However, the call back is not getting triggered but I can see the file popup  and the files on the android system

Comment: I am in strange problem. i have added the plugin in config.xml also cordova add plugin but it is not firing. I am not getting file choose dialog box or anything. No error in firebug as well.

Comment: I know... Try the other plugin in my previous comment... Are you invoking it  from a browser or from the device/simulator

Comment: I am testing it in device as well as basic script related issues/typos test on browser. I tried two plugin but both are not popup file system. Let me try another one.

Comment: What version of Cordova and Sdk  are you using in your project?

Comment: android 6.0.0 cordova 6.4.0

Comment: Tried these plugin but no luck. <plugin name="com.maginsoft.mfilechooser" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="com.megster.cordova.FileChooser" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="com.ourcodeworld.plugins.Filebrowser" source="npm" />

Comment: Strange.. I am using android 5.2.2 , cordova 6.3.1 and sdk23 and I see  the chooser .. Please make sure you are using the command cordova plugin add https://github.com/ourcodeworld/cordova-ourcodeworld-filebrowser.git ,JS callback function and the 'onclick event . In my case I see the browser and the files but the callback is not working.  Sorry.. please send an update if you get it working,,,

Comment: I tried the another plugin as suggested by you. But it is also not showing the prompt. I have added the plugin and i can see them in plugin folder but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSP probably don't allow you to run inline javascript, so the onclick is not doing anything.

Try adding this in your `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag

`script-src 'unsafe-inline';`